# Which music programmes should I consider installing on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I would like to use a music programme on Ubuntu that meets the following requirements:

1. the ability to batch rename, convert and meta tag music files,
2. the ability to scrobble plays in the music programme to Last.fm, and
3. the ability to sync with 6th generation iPod nano and to scrobble iPod plays to Last.fm.

On Windows I would satisfy requirement 1 with **Foobar2000**, which enabled me to run **batch rename processes** with preset naming formats as well as to **convert batches** of music files with finely tuned settings such as output file format, bit rate, output location, naming convention, etc.

I would **sync my iPod and scrobble my iPod plays** to Last.fm using **iTunes** (and both players supported in-player scrobbling to Last.fm).

Is there a single music programme in Ubuntu that can do all this? If not, what is a viable combination of music players that would satisfy the above-mentioned needs?

Note: I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Have you searched for clementine? It's my favourite music player under linux. I'm not sure if it does what you want it to do, try it out and let us know!

Answer (score 0):

Nice programs for converting are `soundconverter` and `winff`. For managing your Music with iPod sync and Last.fm scrobble support there is `banshee` but I don't know how good the iPod sync works and if it can scrobble what you have played on your iPod.

Other music players to take a look at are `rhythmbox`, `guayadeque` and `amarok`. I don't really like amarok, because im to stupid to use it right, but I know many people that really like it.